# ReportingServicesTools module is not digitally signed

Tags: powershell, security, reporting-services, code-signing

The current ExcutionPolicy is `AllSigned`; however, I am attempting to automate the deployment of SSRS packages via the ReportingServicesTools module that Microsoft published (see link below). My deployment implementation is a scrip that calls a series of commands that are made available within the ReportingServicesTools module. Unfortunately, when I try executing the script, I get the following error:

> C:\...\ReportingServicesTools.psm1 is not digitally signed. You cannot
>   run this script on the current system.

I am able to run the script when I change the ExecutionPolicy to `RemoteSigned`. However, this may run afoul with our company's policies.

Before I address this internally, is there anyway that I can get the script to run under an `AllSigned` ExecutionPolicy? I have checked online and everything seems to point to changing the ExecutionPolicy to `RemoteSigned`. So, I assume the answer to my question is no, but I first want to check here that way I have left no stone un-turned.

**ReportingServicesTools:**

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/0.0.4.8

Comment: There are ways to get around the execution policy, but I'd expect all of them to violate your company's policies. The simplest way to deal with an enforced execution policy is to create a code signing certificate, import it, and sign the code yourself. The best way to deal with the issue is to talk to your IT department.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have a code-signing certificate. If I understand what you are saying, I can code-sign a 3rd party module?

Comment: AFAIK yes, that should work. You'd need to repeat that whenever the module is updated, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Understood. Thank you for your assistance.